# Rails, Devise: current_user is nil when overriding RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Rails 3.2.5, Devise 2.1

Using Devise to authenticate Users, and am having a problem when creating a new user.

A user belongs to an Account which I create using a `before_save` filter in the User model.  This works fine and has for a while.

New code requires the user's account information as part of the create method. I rely on a parameter passed in the request, so this is not a good candidate for Model logic.  I have overridden the Devise::RegistrationsController#create method:

```
class DeviseCustom::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super                                  # Call Devise's create
    account = current_user.account         # FAIL! (current_user is nil)
    account.partner_id = current_partner
    account.save!
  end
end
```

`current_user` is `nil` which causes the code to fail.  Even in the case of a failure, I can see that the user and account records *are being saved* in the database -- the logs show the `commit`, and logging `self.inspect` shows all my context (params, and much more) is all still present.

I would have thought that `current_user` would be available in this context -- what's an appropriate way to get at the user I have just created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**: I've never used devise.

My guess is the current_user object hasn't been created, either because there wasn't a reason to (no user credentials) earlier on in the call chain, or because it hasn't yet happend perhaps in #after_save (if that exists?).

Devise uses a #resource method to grab the current instance variable you're trying to save (or so it looks):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L16

What I would do is change the it to:

```
class DeviseCustom::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
      super                                  # Call Devise's create
      account = resource.account         # FAIL! (current_user is nil)
      account.partner_id = resource.current_partner
      account.save!
    end
end
```

You'll probably want to add this to your model:

```
attr_accessor :current_partner
```

which will allow you to access the current_partner from the resource (model).

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Yep, `resource` was the magic.  Thanks!  I should have just looked at the code instead of the horrific `self.inspect` output from the logger :-)  The `current_partner` bit is a method in ApplicationController that I wrote to do look up the soon-to-be-associated Partner record -- it's not related to Devise.  I owe you one!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use the Devise helper methods by including them in my controller
when overriding.

`include Devise::Controllers::Helpers`

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.