# Rails Devise model not saving model in a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise, nested-forms

I have a simple model, `User`, generated via the Devise (version 3.0.4) gem for Rails (version 4.0.2). I've also made a non-Devise model called `Profile`. Profile has two string attributes,`name` and `bio`. Each User `has_one` profile, and each profile `belongs_to` a User. I'm trying to have the User registration form to include Profile attributes, so a nested Profile form in the new User form. I have the form setup correctly, and all user and profile attributes are properly passed to `:params`. **Everything seems to work, except the Profile and it's attributes do not save to the database.** The log shows that `:profile` is nil for the users.
I've done a lot of research and I feel like I've tried everything so I hope someone can catch the problem. Here's the code:

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

**Profile model:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user, :autosave => true
    validates :user_id, presence:true

end
```

**Registrations Controller:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


    def new
        resource = build_resource({})
        resource.build_profile
        respond_with resource

    end



end
```

**The new User form, in `views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`:**

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>


<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>


 <%= f.fields_for :profile do |builder| %>

      <h2><%= builder.label :bio%></h2>
      <p><%= builder.text_field :bio %></p>

      <h2><%= builder.label :name %></h2>
      <p><%= builder.text_field :name %></p>
    <% end %>


  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I don't have anything in the profile controller besides empty existing methods like 'new'.

Comment: You do not have your strong parameter set in the applications controller, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Unsatisfactory Answer:

Given the fact that Devise uses strong params, you cannot pass additional non-User params through the sign_up_params. You can do one of two things. Either add name & bio fields to the User model and save them all at once using the devise form. Or create a blank Profile on registration, then have the user enter a bio and name via a separate form which you can save to the Profile model. I hope that helps.

The devise form delivers signup params which are collected and processed by Create. 
See the full devise controller here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

In your form, you are also generating two additional params :bio and :name. However, you need to capture and process these parameters and generate/save a new Profile in addition to the built in Registration.

You could do something like this to modify the devise create method to save your profile after the new user has been created.

```
# POST /resource
def create
build_resource(sign_up_params)

if resource.save
  @profile = current_user.profile.build(bio: params[:bio], name: params[:name])
  @profile.save

  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

end

I think building the new Profile should work there, though it may not have instantiated current_user, yet. **(Confirmed current_user is not available)**

**EDIT - Try this - Did not work**

```
def create
super  
  profile = resource.profile.build(bio: params[:bio], name: params[:name])
  profile.save
end
```

(Source: [Rails, Devise: current_user is nil when overriding RegistrationsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369941/rails-devise-current-user-is-nil-when-overriding-registrationscontroller))

Comment: It seems like current_user is in fact not instantiated yet. I get the error:"undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass". Any idea on how to do this after instantiation?

Comment: Your edit does solve the problem of current_user being nil, but then I got an error that profile was nil. I figured setting it to a built Profile would make more sense then trying to call the `build` method on a nil object. So instead of `profile = resource.profile.build(bio: params[:bio], name: params[:name])` I have `resource.profile = Profile.new(bio: params[:bio], name: params[:name])`, followed by the save. Also had to replace `build` with `new`. This seems to work, Profile is not nil! Now just the attributes :bio and :name are nil...

Comment: Unsatisfactory answer: Devise uses strong parameters. So any additional parameters passed through will be sanitized and discarded (which is why the :bio and :name keys are nil. From my read of the documentation, you cannot add additional params the sign_up_params. [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters). See my revise answer for thoughts.

Comment: I don't know about the sign_up_params and the other Devise params, but when I submit the form, I know for sure the `profile_attributes` are in the `params` hash. I can print them to console from the create method. Though when I try to create the profile from the params, the console prints `Unpermitted parameters: email, password, password_confirmation, profile_attributes`. I am still new to Rails so I'm probably misunderstanding this, but I thought strong parameters involved filtering out certain attributes for a model creation. So how are those parameters made "unpermitted"?